# Reduce Firestore read operations

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Today I launched an app on play store which uses firestore in its backend.
I have a spark account(free account) and reads from firestore are limited to 50k.
After 6 hours of launch my read chart shows 38k reads.

I read something about firestore that "Cloud Firestore version 16.0.0 it was added the ability to control whether DocumentReference.get() and Query.get() should fetch data from the server only, the cache only".

This is my code which leads to read operation from firestore. Can someone help me to modify my code so that it does not always call firestore and retrieves data from cache.

```
Future<void> _getUserDetails() async {
    String uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    DocumentSnapshot doc = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('UserDatabase')
        .doc(uid)
        .get();

    if (doc.exists) {
      // this will check availability of document
      setState(() {
        branch = doc.data()['Branch'];
        semester = doc.data()['Semester'];
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        branch = 'User is not available';
        semester = 'User is not available';
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore: Fetch data from server only if there is an update else fetch from cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61422975/firestore-fetch-data-from-server-only-if-there-is-an-update-else-fetch-from-cac)

Comment: https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-drastically-reduce-the-number-of-reads-when-no-documents-are-changed-in-firestore-8760e2f25e9e

Answer (score 1):

I have been thinking of this for a bit too. In my app, i have a splash screen, i'm planning to get my userdetails inside splash screen. After that, the data will be passed to another screen which will need certain data. I think this method will save firestore read. Let me know if you got an idea for this problem too!

Comment: I used shared preference to save my data from firestore. When any user goes to home screen post register screen/login screen then i store his details from firestore in cache memory using shared preferences. This happens every time a user goes to my home screen for the first time so once user details are stored in cache it will no longer call firestore for read operations and whenever needed user data for some reason i extracted it from cache memory rather than calling it from firestore. Also if you allow update then make sure that you update shared pref along with update in firestore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to store all the collection in a doc and I got the same problem for now... i'm trying to store that collection into a array to use these collection and with that filter the data to do less reads on my aplication, cause i has around 200 products but per each user are doing 1400 reads or more...

at least I read overthere a document that use firebase funtions "Data Bundle" to reduce the reads cost drasticaly, but this year firebase funtions are only for Blaze plan.

The Article:
https://dev.to/moga/decrease-read-costs-of-firestore-using-firestore-data-bundles-30e9